# Laravel Blade how to pass $attributes to component from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have a blade component containing `$attributes`; It would be a bag of attributes when the component called from another blade template but when from the controller via `view()` the `$attributes` is undefined! How can I pass data as `$attributes` from the controller?

Component: `sample`

```php
<div {{ $attributes->except('content') }}>{{ $content }}</div>
```

Template: works well.

```php
...
<x-sample class="test" content="test"/>
...
```

Controller: Error **Undefined variable $attributes**

```php
$attributes = ['class' => 'test', 'content' => 'test'];
view('components.sample', $attributes)->render();
view('components.sample', ['attributes' => $attributes])->render();
view('components.sample')->with($attributes)->render();
```

**UPDATE (Solution):**

It works:

```php
view('components.sample', [
    'prop1' => '...',
    'prop2' => '...',
    'attributes' => new ComponentAttributeBag(['attr1' => '...', 'attr2' => '...']),
])->render();
```

Comment: Why are  you trying to render a component as a view from a controller? That kind of defeats the point of a component

Comment: There are nested and complex data, and I prefer to put logic in the controller and use the template engine in the view layer.

Comment: The trick with complex UI is using something that simplifies it. I would recommend looking into VUE.js if things really get complicated. It's not perfect but its better than your current solution(attempt)

Comment: It seems it is possible via the component php class. I thought there could be a straight forward solution ;)

Comment: The ComponentAttributeBag works but is pretty ugly. Another option is you can create a dedicated view file for rendering the custom component, then render the decided view file normally: `view('render-sample', ['prop1' => '...', 'prop2' => '...'])->render();`. Or better yet rewrite your code so you can move the component rendering to blade instead.

Answer (score 0):

what is happening is components inherit variable from view, if you define your variable from home view for example, it should work in component from that view. Then when you include the view to about page the variables wont be recognized since they are not inherited from about view. And in Laravel you cannot pass data directly form controller to component. but laravel have solved it by [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers).

Since I dont like too much complication especially with providers I edited my `AppServiceProvider` you can create your own provider.

in `YourServiceProvider` in my case `AppServiceProvider` in boot() function there are three options you can use one. I recommend there 3rd one since its clean

```
public function boot()
    {
        // option1 -  Every single view
         View::share('shops', Shop::orderBy('name')->get());

        // option2 - Gradular views with wildcards
         View::composer(['client.*'], function ($view){
             $view->with('shops', Shop::orderBy('name')->get());
         });

        // option3 - Dedicated class

        View::composer(['client.includes.*','client.create-product','client.cart'], ShopsComposer::class);
         View::composer(['client.includes.*','client.cart'], CartComposer::class);
    }
```

If you use the 3rd method you have to create `ViewComposer` class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use App\Models\CartItem;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class ShopsComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view){
        $shop = auth()->user()->shops->sortBy('name');
        $cartItem = new CartItem();
        $cartCount = 0;
        if (Session::has('cartId')) {
            $carts = Session::get('cartId');
            $cartItems = $cartItem->with('products')->where('cart_id', '=', $carts->id)->get();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $cartCount += $item->quantity;
            }
        } 
        $view->with('shopsComposer', $shop)->with('cartCount', $cartCount);
    }
}
```

The variables you define there will be available to all the views. that includes components. Since component inherit variable from view file.

I am sorry I had to share my working example, since I am running out of time. I hope it works if I understood well your question.